# .Net Core TFS 2017 build losing some appsettings in appsettings.json file

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, .net-core

I have a strange situation where when I build in release mode versus debug mode, some of the settings within appsettings.json suddenly don't exist in what is published to the drop folder of TFS 2017.  Sometimes, this even happens if I'm building in debug mode.  What causes this and how do I stop it from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out finally.  What was actually occurring is that I was doing the publish command on the solution.  The solution had a web project as well as several web APIs within it.  What was happening is that it was taking what appears to be the web API with a web.config and using that to publish the app settings.  So instead of grabbing the app settings of the web project itself, it would grab the appsettings.json from the web api.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with similar situation not on TFS/Source control but as part of the published files to a source (ftp) location and it came down to this, check if your `project.Json` file has the build option's copy to output section to include appSettings like file. sample below

```
"buildOptions": {
"copyToOutput": {
     "include":   [
                   "appsettings*.json",
                   "App*.config"
                  ]
                }
```

Comment: It is copying the appsettings.json file itself, it just doesn't copy all of the actual settings within the file.  To make it even stranger, I now have a build in TFS 2017 where if you trigger it manually on the server, it gets all the app settings however if you trigger it through CI it fails to write all the appsettings to the file.  So the file itself is there, with some of the settings in it, just not all of them which means the application doesn't work.

Comment: wow! so the content within the file is not being pulled over.. am so sorry to hear that and I honestly have no clue why this would happen. hope you land on a solution soon :)